# Compile-time aspects throwing NoSuchMethodError in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I am getting an error when running my "compile-time-weaver" classes from Maven on a JAR file that is included in my Spring Boot 1.2.2 WAR.

So, I have a jar, ctms-components.jar, that I run my aspect (e.g., a method timing profiler) on using MAVEN.  Then, Spring Boot puts it all in an embedded WAR (I'm using Tomcat).  I see both the aspectj woven classes like AJC Closures(), etc. and I see the logs from Maven are weaving my classes as per my pointcuts.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <source>${compiler.version}</source>
                <target>${compiler.version}</target>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <complianceLevel>${compiler.version}</complianceLevel>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>cdot.ctms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ctms-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <weaveDependencies>
                    <weaveDependency>
                      <groupId>cdot.ctms</groupId>
                      <artifactId>ctms-components</artifactId>
                    </weaveDependency>
                </weaveDependencies>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Here is an excerpt from my maven log.

```
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(cdot.base.DataAccessObject cdot.ctms.layer.services.comm.device.doppler.facade.DopplerFacade.getDopplerExchange())' in Type 'cdot.ctms.layer.services.comm.device.doppler.facade.DopplerFacade' (DopplerFacade.java:78) advised by around advice from 'cdot.aop.profiler.MethodTimerAspect' (ctms-aspects-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!MethodTimerAspect.class(from MethodTimerAspect.java))
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(cdot.base.DataAccessObject cdot.ctms.layer.services.comm.device.doppler.facade.DopplerFacade.getDopplerRawDataExchange())' in Type 'cdot.ctms.layer.services.comm.device.doppler.facade.DopplerFacade' (DopplerFacade.java:84) advised by around advice from 'cdot.aop.profiler.MethodTimerAspect' (ctms-aspects-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!MethodTimerAspect.class(from MethodTimerAspect.java))
```

My Spring Boot WAR shows the AJC Closures are bundled in the WAR:

[image]

The ERROR I get when running the application is:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cdot.aop.profiler.MethodTimerAspect.aspectOf()Lcdot/aop/profiler/MethodTimerAspect**

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cdot.aop.profiler.MethodTimerAspect.aspectOf()Lcdot/aop/profiler/MethodTimerAspect;
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    ... 87 more
```

I don't understand why it does compile time weaving, adds it to my Spring Boot WAR just fine, and also includes the ctms-aspects.jar, but cannot find the method on my Aspect?

Answer (score 1):

The AspectJ runtime library *aspectjrt.jar* must be on your classpath, so it should be a Maven `<dependency>` not just for the AspectJ Maven Plugin but also for the Maven module as such.